# ansible start multiple service and truncate name service

Tags: ansible, roles

I want to start multiple service on playbook, but I want to remove end of service string like :
a.service => a
b.service => b

because I cannot use service a.service start, but I have to use service a start

because variable item is stored in default/main.yml role playbook like that :

```
name_services:
  - a.service
  - b.service
```

on main.yml

```
- name: start multiple service
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: started
  with_items: "{{ name_services }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter [splitext](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names)

```yaml
- name: start multiple service
  service:
    name: "{{ item | splitext | first }}"
    state: started
  with_items: "{{ name_services }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to achieve it, given that the services have only one dot (`.`) in their string value. you split based on the dot and take the first chunk (string before the dot).

```
  - debug:
      var: item.split('.')[0]
    loop: "{{ name_services }}"
```

another way would be to remove the `.service` part from the string:

```
  - debug:
      var: item.replace('.service','')
    loop: "{{ name_services }}"
```

cheers